# Azure API management service status says as stopped. How to restart the service?

Tags: azure-api-management

Azure API management service status is stopped as shown below
[image]

Azure subscription service is disabled when I am trying to create a new instance.
Can you please provide pointers to help me resolve this and restart the service?

Appreciate your help

Tried to google for restarting the service, but could not find relevant sources. I am looking to restart the service.

Comment: Have you given try to start it directly from the portal? Do you see any error while starting the service.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I can see the Statuses of Azure APIM Service like Activating and Online even after removing the Built-in Todo APIS from the APIM Services.

As given in this MS Q&A Forum #[466132](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/466132/how-to-stop-start-azure-apim-service-using-portal), Other than managing the APIs such as create, delete, modify and delete operations, there are no management options/features to start/restart/stop the APIM Service in Azure.

Regarding the Status, I didn't see many options to modify it on the APIM Serice Portal:
[image]

1. Browse the Gateway URL and Developer Portal URLs of your APIM Service and check the status of APIM Service in properties or overview blade.
2. Try checking the Activity Logs from the APIM Service Portal, where you can find the data about when & Why the APIM Service Stopped, and these logs shows complete operations happened on that APIM Service:
   [image]